# How to use auto return type with SWIG

Tags: java, c++, swig, auto

I want to write in c++ code like this and generate it's wrapper in java:

```
class A() {
public:
   const auto & getNumbers() const { return _numbers; }
private:
   vector<int> _numbers; 
}
```

but SWIG returns error (`Error: Syntax error in input(3).`) in line with auto.

`const vector<int> & getNumbers() const { return _numbers; }` works fine, but I'd prefer to use `auto` syntax in this case.

Anyone knows how to use `auto` with SWIG ?

Comment: whats the advantage of not writing `const std::vector<int>&` for the return type?

Comment: You can't do that. Use explicit types. (This is a good idea anyway; as a user of `A`, I don't want to have to look at the private implementation details in order to figure out what the return type is.)

Comment: maybe trailing return type works, tough thats more typing rather than less.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - it has advantages but they're not significant. 
I think it's less typing, less redundancy, less work if vector inner type will change.